# I wish to load a subset of data from an angular resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My JSON data looks like this and is contained in a file called 'parks.json':

```
{
    "description": "Farnborough features a good amount of green space and is indeed surrounded by plenty more. Our Parks section aims to tell you, not only where they all are but a little bit about the history behind them and the people who look after them today.",
    "id": "parks",
    "name": "Parks",
    "locations": [
        {
            "name": "Queen Elizabeth Park",
            "lat": 51.29692,
            "lng": -0.76080000000000003,
            "synopsis": "Once part of Windsor Great Park"
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

The following $resource query will retrieve the above fragment of data:

```
return $resource('locations/:categoryId.json', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params:{categoryId:'categories'}, isArray:true}
  });
```

The categoryId being passed in is 'parks', so the above code would retrieve my entire Parks.jsonfile and load it into an object. This is fine but, I want to extract just part of it into an array or object.

My question is how could I adapt the above to extract just the locations? I am especially interested in the lat and lng values. I have already got various other things working and need to suss out this kind of action, as I am not very familiar with how to do this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- This probably isn't the best use of `$resource`. `$http` would be preferrable in this scenario, because you're not really dealing with a RESTful web service. You're apparently dealing with `GET`s on .json files. Using `$resource` will instantiate a bunch of extra functions and overhead you don't need and can't use.
- The best place to filter the results you're getting back would be at the server. I know you can't really do that with a .json file, but it's worth mentioning.
- This really isn't an issue with $resource or even Angular, so much as it is an issue with JavaScript, what you want to do is get a subset of objects from an array.

All of that said... if you *must* do this using $resource, you could do something like the following pseudo-code:

```
// a factory to create your Park resource service.
app.factory('Park', ['ngResource', function($resource) {
    //your Park resource constructor.
    var Park = $resource('locations/:categoryId.json', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{categoryId:'categories'}, isArray:true}
      });

    //a "static" function on Park to filter results.
    Park.filter = function(parks, predicate) {
        var results = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < parks.length; i++) {
            var park = parks[i];
            if(predicate(park)) {
                results.push(angular.copy(park));
            }
        }
        return results;
    };

    //return the constructor
    return Park;
}]);

// a controller example to consume your service.
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Park) {
    // get all parks in category 123
    var allParks = Park.query({categoryId: 123});

    // filter the parks down to the ones named "Hooterville Park"
    $scope.parks = Park.filter(allParks, function(park) {
        return park.name === 'Hooterville Park';
    });
});
```

The thing is, $resource is made to be used with a RESTful resource like so:

```
// create a basic resource.
var Foo = $resource('/Foo/:id');

// get and update one item.
var foo = Foo.get(123, function() {
    foo.name = 'Test';
    foo.email = 'blah@sample.com';
    foo.$save();
});

// create a new item.
var foo2 = new Foo();
foo2.name = 'New guy';
foo2.email = 'new@guy.com';
foo.$save();

// get and update a bunch of items.
var foos = Foo.query();
for(var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++) {
   var fooItem = foos[i];
   fooItem.name = 'Foo ' + i;
   fooItem.$save();
}
```

So unless you're going to do that stuff, I'd say go ahead and just use $http.

Comment: Thanks @blesh - Ultimately I will move this to a restful service but at the moment I am going through a mixture of learning and prototyping, as I learn to use Javascript in new ways. So your reply has been very, very useful. My project will move away from using plain json files fairly soon.